# Are MAC OS X wifi credentials limited to each user and not the entire computer?

Tags: macos

I just logged into a mac in my school and use my personal school log in credentials to use the wifi at the school. I can forget the network because i don't have access to the settings. But I just wanted to know that no one else can use my wifi credentials when they log into another OS X user account.

Can someone please help me. I don't want to leave my wifi credentials on an public computer. I don't mind if it is only limited to my OS X user log in.

Thanks.

Comment: Wifi settings should be stored per user. If there not, that's a bad security practice in Apples case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok if you're asking the Mac to forget the network. The only thing I can think of storing your passwords is signing into iCloud Keychain...... So if you signed in with your Apple ID in the iCloud system pane then I would be concerned a little but it doesn't sound like it.